# Using pandas date as the X values of a bar graph Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, date

The code below outputs the bar graph using `graph_vals` and `Monthly_indx`, however the x values of the graph `Monthly_indx` are messed up and impossible to read when displayed. How would I be able to fix the x axis and make the graph readable?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph_vals = np.array([0.0, 15.58698486544634, 62.39522773472678, 53.102459267328186,
                       20.664598839134662, 37.43748926661284, 24.919985065059905, 2.462993387475203,
                       20.53746782047295, 87.85805111410333, 38.70428059326558, 31.56608531221292,
                       7.418190883067737, 17.10281023326888, 31.804189226978277, 30.05396124982128,
                       64.40080197706149, 33.29684656571501, 52.913157810513006, 20.913775029581142,
                       68.41187918506716, 47.56850690090707, 56.2736117598243, 31.25351961092795,
                       72.49099807107945, 44.95116145453175, 78.0696975321658, 54.60288966093484])

Monthly_indx = pd.date_range( pd.to_datetime('2019-05-08'),  pd.to_datetime('2021-09-08'), freq='MS')
print(len(graph_vals), len(Monthly_indx))

ax1 = pd.DataFrame({'Monthly PnLs':graph_vals, 'Months':Monthly_indx })
ax = ax1.plot.bar(y='Monthly PnLs',x='Months', rot=0)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Matplotlib, use `plt.setp()` to tilt your x-labels:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
```

You can adjust the angle to your liking.

Comment: That is not a good solution for it either since it is not readable in that case as well. I have updated the code for you to see what your code looks like

Comment: again, you can adjust the angle... making the angle steeper will separate the numbers a bit. Also have you considered NOT using 0's everywhere? maybe that will help with your 'readability'